# 'foreach' query works on Localhost but not on Server - PHP, MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, localhost

This query below on localhost (PHP/5.4.22)

```
<?php
global $db;    
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM player WHERE playerID = '181783'") or die(mysqli_error($db));                
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $fName = $row['fName'];
    echo "First Name: " . $fName;    
}           
?>
```

How ever on my webhost (PHP/5.3.28)

this query returns

> First Name: First Name: First Name: First Name: First Name:

There is currently only 1 result that returns where playerID = 181783, and it should echo the name 'Mario'

When I run the query like below on my webhost it works and echos Mario.

```
$query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM player WHERE playerID = '181783'");                             
$result = $query2->fetch_object();                
echo $result->fName;
```

So this must mean the db connection is set up correctly, as query2 is on the same page and working, just for some reason with query one it doesn't echo the result, but shows 'First Name:' 5 times.

It is like this for all foreach() functions I have used throughout my site, so I cannot just query 2.

To summaries, both queries work on localhost, when uploading to my webhost only query 2 works.

There are no errors despite error_reporting(E_ALL); being enabled

What should I do?
Thanks.

Edit- db config

```
//MySQLI configuration
$_CONFIG['mysql']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$_CONFIG['mysql']['username'] = '#';
$_CONFIG['mysql']['password'] = '#';
$_CONFIG['mysql']['database'] = '#';

//Initialize MySQLi connection
$db = new mysqli($_CONFIG['mysql']['hostname'], $_CONFIG['mysql']['username'], $_CONFIG['mysql']['password'], $_CONFIG['mysql']['database']);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die("MySQLi error: ".$db->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: What does `print_r($row)` say? Are you sure you have the same table population on both servers?

Comment: maybe showing your db config file can help here.

Comment: print_r($fName) returns nothing again, I've added my db config to the post.

Comment: DB config isn't the problem, check my anser: `Mysqli_Result` doesn't implement `Travesrable` prior to version 5.4, your webserver is running 5.3. That's all. Using a `while` loop solves the problem, as would upgrading the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simply that `mysqli::query` returns an instance of the `mysqli_result` class, which didn't implement the `Traversable` interface until PHP 5.4 came along ([see the man pages](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) under change log).
Your webhost, by your own admission is running 5.3: *"webhost (PHP/5.3.28)"*, so your code won't work, because the value of `$query` (which isn't a query but a resultset) isn't iterable.

Just change the code to what we're all used to see:

```
$result = $db->query('Your query here');
if (!$result) throw new Exception('Query Failed!');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo 'First name: ', $row['fName'];
}
```

Job done.

*Notes:*
This fixed the problem, true enough, but you'd be best served with an upgrade of your server, or at least *a test environment that replicates the production environment!*

I also noticed the `or die` in your code. Please, don't do that, especially not in a *production/live* environment. Google *"or die must die"*. It's an out-dated construct. It's code-smell and doesn't really *do* anything, except for showing the clients the system's error messages. That's not nice.

Comment: @user1626410: Take note: whenever you encounter code working in one environment, but failing in another: check output of `phpinfo()` and compare enabled/installed extensions, then check the versions, and check the changelogs on php.net. Think of these two steps as the basic checklist like you'd do with hardware: _are the cables connected properly_ and _is the device noticeably broken_

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Need to add `$rows = $query->fetch_array();`

```
 $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM player WHERE playerID = '181783'") or die(mysqli_error($db));    
$rows = $query->fetch_array();              
foreach ($rows as $row) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your first code snippet $query  only executes query :
```

**You are missing** $query->fetch_object();

**Example**:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: You're not explaining why the first snippet actually _worked_ on the localhost of the OP. `mysqli::query` returns an instance of `mysqli_result` which, since PHP 5.4 implements `Traversable`, so an iterator can be used on it. The server runs version 5.3. Links to documentation that backs this up are in my answer